# Binding to a DropDownList in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

Previously, I was using this in my model

```
 public List<SelectListItem> StatusList { get; set; }
 public string Status { get; set; }
```

and this in my view to bind to the Dropdownlist

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, Model.StatusList, "")
```

but if I want to use

```
  public List<ICode> StatusList { get; set; }
```

where ICode is as below

```
 public interface ICode
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    ICodeGroup CodeGroup { get; set; }
    string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    string LongDescription { get; set; }
}
```

What should I do in my view and model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cybernate's solution works.  You could also do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, 
     new SelectList(Model.StatusList, "Id", "ShortDescription"))
```

Cybernate's version will do stronger type checking, but SelectList is more encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, 
 Model.StatusList.Select(a=> 
  new SelectListItem(){
   Text=a.ShortDescription, Value=a.Id.ToString()
  }),
 "")
```