# populating dropdownlist from db in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to populate a dropdownlist from a selected column of a table.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DeleteRole(RoleManager model)
    {
         //select all roleNames from db

           var getRole = from r in Session.Query<RoleManager>()
                      select r.roleName.ToList();


        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model.roleName)
```

It is giving an error that No overload for method 'DropDownListFor' takes 1 arguments

Comment: You need to passed the dictionary like (key,value) collection for DropDownListFor along with the model

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.roleName, Model.roleName) this one also not works

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247871/binding-to-a-dropdownlist-in-mvc3

Comment: Check this [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9CJmLbnFko‎)

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145641/how-can-i-reuse-a-dropdownlist-in-several-views-with-net-mvc/19146077#19146077